# Facebook Graph API Filters - What options are available?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

It seems that you can make a call to the Graph API that looks like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/checkins?since=yesterday

Apparently you can pass either a UNIX timestamp or any valid strtotime value.

The questions...how do you know what other options are available to you in the request?  I don't see any documentation about this "since" filter or any other similar filter.   Is this information just trickling down from people who know some API engineers at Facebook?

I know that there are some things that you can do in FQL that are similar to what I was describing but I want to stay with the Graph API if I can.

Thanks
--Tony

Answer (score 8):

Anothony Lee:

> **since, until** - (a unix timestamp or any date accepted by strtotime):
>   EG: since=yesterday until=now, since=6+months+ago until=3+months+ago,
>   since=10/01/2011 until=10/11/2011

another example

> &since=noon+monday+last+week &until=10+minutes+ago.

Answer (score -1):

you need to provide the date filter as shown in the below link. time_range should be attached to the insights.

try this
https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/me?fields=id%2Cname%2Cadaccounts%7Bcampaigns%7Badsets%7Bads%7Binsights.time_range(%7B'since'%3A'2020-05-01'%2C'until'%3A'2020-05-01'%7D)%7Badset_id%2Ccampaign_id%2Cad_id%2Cclicks%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D&access_token=

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. While the url may answer the question, unless you include the key details in your answer, your answer will be useless if the link breaks. See [answer] for more detail.